# d3.request is not a function. get JSON from API Rest

Tags: json, rest, api, d3.js

I want to use JSON data from an API and use it in a chart. For this, I did so:

```
d3.request (url hidden)
  .mimeType ("application / json")
  .response (function (xhr) {return JSON.parse (xhr.responseText);});
```

but I got this error "d3.request is not a function" what am i doing wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch

Comment: Most probably, you are using D3 **v5**. However, as of v5 the d3-request module has been deprecated and [dropped](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#changes-in-d3-50) from the full bundle. You need to either switch to the Fetch API adopted by v5 or separately import module d3-request.

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly means you've forgotten to import d3.js or accidentally imported multiple times. 
Please check in your complied HTML file if you have imported d3 library correctly.
Best would be to share a jsfiddle example to resolve the issue.

Comment: @littlegrasshopper 
I can't access the link please share the link  i can view

Comment: @littlegrasshopper There is a separate library for d3 requests
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-request.v1.min.js"></script>

Comment: @littlegrasshopper 
d3.request has been depricated please use d3-fetch instead
https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch